Why does keras deep learning model only requires loss function but not its gradient?
When I implement my own neural network, I need to pass both how the model is supposed to forward(to calculate model's loss) and backward its loss. But keras model only requires a formula for how the loss is calculated to add a custom loss function. Why is that?
Reference link: Custom loss function
I can't really figure this out. Please help!

The whole point of these libraries is to remove the need to make these calculations yourself. https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/autodiff
